# Where do os_logs live? Can they be parsed?

Tags: xcode, logging

With aslmsg, it was possible to iterate through each message of a log to create NSStrings and then do whatever we wanted with them.  I'm moving to use os_log, but don't see an outlet where I can parse through the logged messages...are the logs only visible through the terminal or is there some object living somewhere where I can access these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a ["Unified Logging and Activity Tracing"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/721/)
session at WWDC 2016. From the transcript:

> In this new system logging data is kept in a compressed binary format on disk, it's called a .tracev3 file.
>
> Those files are now stored under /var/db/diagnostics with additional supporting files in /var/db/uuidtext. There are new tools to access that data, there's a new Console, a new log command line tool and one of the things you have to keep in mind is because the data is now stored in a binary format you must use the new tools to access it. So you can no longer grep through logs you have to use our tools to do the surfing through it.

So the files are accessible, but not suitable for parsing. Reading
the log messages is only supported via the `/usr/bin/log` tool
and the Console.

Comment: That's a bummer...  What do they recommend people do when they want to parse and send that data elsewhere at runtime?  Are we supposed to keep using asl?