# CocoaLumberjack Retrieving System logs on top of regular logs in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, cocoalumberjack

Prior to iOS 10, I could create an instance of an ASL Logger, and set it up to capture the system logs coming out of NSLog in other frameworks that our app was using, like so: 
DDASLLogCapture.setCaptureLevel(.All)
DDASLLogCapture.start()

However, with iOS 10 now, this no longer works. In the file DDASLLogCapture.m, the entirety of capturing the system logs comes out of banking off of notifications from the system that there's new log messages in the database with the key kNotifyASLDBUpdate which is equal to "com.apple.system.logger.message". This key doesn't seem to have changed in iOS 10, as I can inspect the notify_keys.h file in order to view them, but the notifications don't occur in iOS 10, I'm assuming as a result of moving over to os_log.

This being the case, what can be done now to retrieve system logs that were being directed to console output that are no longer being picked up by the DDASLLogCapture object?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39734145/where-do-os-logs-live-can-they-be-parsed. Apple does not provide an API to read the os_log messages.

Comment: Damn that's a bummer. But you never responded to their other comment...what are we to do now instead? Doesn't seem like asl even works in its current consideration anymore.

Comment: Didn't know if you had any suggestions is all I was asking.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't. If you need an API then I would suggest to file a bug report at Apple.